# Node not finding dependencies from Gruntfile

Tags: node.js, macos, gruntjs, npm, angular-fullstack

I've been using the Yeoman fullstack-angular generator, and it was working great about a week ago.

Now, after generating a new app, node is unable to add in the wired-in dependencies in the Gruntfile.js. Basically, I have to install all the dependencies that should be resolved with `npm install`. After installing about a dozen npm packages, like jit-grunt, jshint, etc, grunt build/serve will finish, but the app doesn't load in the browser.

I'm sure this is a node/npm issue, as the app generator was working about a week ago. I've tried completely uninstalling and reinstalling. Any guesses as to why this is happening?

Although I get the same behavior with different npm versions, right now I'm at:

npm : 3.3.12
node: 4.2.1
grunt-cli: 0.1.13
grunt: 0.4.5

I'm also getting this error message when I'm installing these packages manually, I feel like it might be related:

```
Ryans-MacBook-Pro:appTest nonzero$ npm install jit-grunt --save-dev
app-test@0.0.0 /Users/nonzero/Programming/appTEST
└── (empty)

npm ERR! code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove local `node_modules` folder, and then run `npm cache clean`. Maybe it will help.